# Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry for email

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-blade

I have done a Laravel project where user can update their profile with name email password
while updating the user profile I am getting **Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry** with email,
in user table email is unique ...how can I handle this error with the message "email has been already taken" so that this will not throw the query exception error
here is my blade file

```
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
            Email
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" value="{{ (isset($user_update)) ? pdate->email : '' }}" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email Here">
        </div>
        @error('email')
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>
                   {{ $message }}
                </strong>
            </span>
        @enderror
    </div>
```

here is my controller for the update method of the user

```
    public function update(UpdateRequestUser $request, User $user) {
        $password=Auth::user()->password;
        $oldpassword=$request->old_password;
        $newpassword=$request->new_password;
        $confirmpassword=$request->confirm_password;
        if(Hash::check($oldpassword, $password)) {
            if($newpassword===$confirmpassword) {
                $user = Auth::user();

                $user->password=Hash::make($newpassword);
                $user->name=$request->name;
                $user->email=$request->email;
                $user->save();
                Auth::logout();
                toastr()->success('password changed successfully');
                return redirect()->route('login');
            } else {
                toastr()->info('password missmatch');
                return redirect()->back();
            }
        }
        if(!(Hash::check($oldpassword, $password))) {
            toastr()->info('Old password  missmatch');
            return redirect()->back();
        }
        //
    }
```

my validation request rule is

```
    return [
        'name'=>'required',
        'email'=>'required',
        'confirm_password'=>'required',
        'new_password'=>'required',
        'old_password'=>'required',
        //
    ];
```

I want to show the error message in the form that the email has been already taken so that my run time project will not show the query exception in the future...
the profile update method is working fine without updating the email... I just want to show the error message mention above

Comment: `'email'=>'required|unique',` here `unique` is missing in validation

Comment: i understand what you want to say ...adding  ***'email'=>'required|unique* will throw the error message as expected .....using this user even can't update their name password too

Comment: ** 'email' => 'required|unique:users,email,'.$this->route('user')->id **  on changing this to validation has resolved this problem

Answer (score 0):

Hello I think that your request class with a validation method may look like  this

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => ['required', 'max:50'],
            'email' => ['required', 'max:50', 'email', Rule::unique('users')],
            'confirm_password'=>'required',
            'new_password'=>'required',
            'old_password'=>'required',
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the latest version of Laravel (v8) you can do this:

```
Validator::make($data, [
  'email' => [
    'required',
    Rule::unique('your-table')->ignore($user->id),
  ],
]);
```